# Struggling to find an installer to insulate the cavities in my loft

Tags: insulation, attic, uk

I'm not a builder or an expert by any stretch of the imagination, so please forgive me in advance.

For context, I live in a 1960s mid-terrace 3-bed ex-council house in East Sussex, UK. We have a loft that has insulation on top of the ceiling below. We also have cavity wall insulation on the front external facing wall.

In the top-floor bedrooms instead of the external wall meeting the ceiling at 90 degrees, the ceiling is curved to meet the wall. This leaves a cavity behind where the ceiling meets the wall.

[image: picture of ceiling meeting wall]

We often get bad surface mould on this curved part of the ceiling in the winter. I've identified that this is because the cavity is lacking insulation so is much colder and it appears that the cavity might just be a void between the eves and roof tiles.

Having looked in the loft I can see small gaps between the eves and see the cavity. It appears when the insulation was fitted (previous owner) the installer didn't insulate this cavity. It looks quite hard to access from the loft, though there is a small gap.

[image: Photo from loft hatch showing eave and cavaty]

I've contacted multiple local insulation specialists in the UK and either they don't reply to my enquiries or say they don't offer this service.

I'm at a bit of a loss, maybe I'm looking for the wrong specialism but I don't know what it is I have as it's an unusual ceiling configuration. If anyone knows why my ceiling and roof are like this and can give me a better understanding of what type of tradesperson I should be looking for that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking us to recommend someone, that's explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you're asking how to find someone, that's pretty well off-topic too. If you're asking how _you_ can insulate that area, that's our bailiwick, but please [edit] to make that more clear. In the US, most big-box home improvement stores will loan an insulation blower for free if you buy blow in insulation from them. That's probably your answer here. It's messy - you'll want a good dust mask, but entirely DIYable...

Comment: I guess I'm asking what kinds of tradespeople or specialism I am looking for and if anyone knows why the ceiling is like this. I'm trying to narrow down what it is I need to look for, not looking for specific recommendations.

Comment: Sounds like the answer, then, is that you need to keep calling insulation companies until you can get a couple to come out & give you estimates, or resign yourself to a DIY approach.

Comment: As to why the ceiling is like this: 'architecture'. I used to live somewhere similar (built ~1949) and an architect friend said it was 'arts and crafts' style to have steep overhanging roofs and the roofs going up slightly into the loft space.  Means you got more headroom inside and a very decent height loft. See eg [Letchworth](https://www.greatbritishlife.co.uk/homes-and-gardens/places-to-live/22584406.letchworth-garden-citys-rich-arts-crafts-heritage/) for similar design ideas.

Comment: Not architecture so much as efficiency--you get a lot of usable floor space on a small overall footprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have several choices:

1. Blown insulation, eg cellulose
2. Spray foam
3. Shove wool batts (eg Rockwool) into the gap
4. Insulate from below, ie insulated ceiling board

#1 and #2 need a professional contractor with the equipment, #3 and #4 you could do by yourself or a general handyperson.  For #4 you would need to make good the decorations afterwards (plastering and painting), although you might need to do that anyway to freshen up the mouldy parts.

#3 would be the simplest - get some 'loft roll', which is typically fibreglass or mineral wool, but can also be recycled polyester or sheeps wool if you prefer those materials, and shove it into the gap.  Use pieces of wood, broom handles or similar to push the wool into the gaps.  Keep stuffing it in until the gap is full.

For #4, fit [insulated plasterboard](https://www.buildingmaterials.co.uk/info-hub/plaster-plasterboard/insulated-plasterboard-guide) on top of the existing ceiling, then redecorate. The key is to make sure it's well sealed so there are no air draughts between the PB and the existing ceiling - as the ceiling appears textured you might fill the gap somehow, or remove the textured plaster (beware that some old 'Artex' can have asbestos in it, so I wouldn't sand it)

I'm assuming this corner is not where ventilation comes from: if it is, you might need to arrange other ventilation for the loft.  For example, if filling this space would block soffit ventilation, consider adding air bricks (in the end walls) or tile vents.

Comment: Another thought is to take out the ceiling plasterboard, fill the void with insulation from below, and then fit new ceiling boards. Likely only worth doing if the ceiling is in bad condition and needs replacing - at which point you might still consider insulated ceiling boards rather than filling the cavity, especially if this is the only route for ventilation.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of where I am thinking, pull the ceiling down or go in via the roof by lifting the roof tiles but that would require scaffolding etc. The voids in the loft and too narrow and deep to reach even with a stick and the void runs along the entire length of the house on both sides. I'm starting to understand why the previous owner never had this section insulated, it's inaccessible.

Comment: Strictly you wouldn't need to pull the ceiling down.  Just fit [insulated plasterboard](https://www.buildingmaterials.co.uk/info-hub/plaster-plasterboard/insulated-plasterboard-guide) on top of the existing ceiling, then redecorate.  The key is to make sure it's well sealed so there are no air drafts between the PB and the existing ceiling - as the ceiling appears textured you might fill the gap somehow, or remove the textured plaster (beware that some old 'Artex' can have asbestos in it, so I wouldn't sand it)

Comment: @user1908704, your "thought" should be in your answer, not a comment.

Comment: The ventilation I mentioned is not for the loft. It's for the _roof_. This answer doesn't address that adequately.

Comment: Maybe it is in the UK, but here in the US "blown in insulation" is most definitely _NOT_ a "professional contractor thing". As I noted in a comment on the OP, most every big-box DIY store in the country will loan you (free of charge) an insulation blower if you buy bags of blow in insulation from them. It's definitely, hot, sweaty, dusty, uncomfortable work up in an attic in the summer - I can attest to that since I did it in my house.

Comment: @FreeMan we don't use blown insulation in lofts, we use it in cavity walls. That's a professional job for drilling the holes, injecting the insulation, plugging the holes afterwards. You could maybe convince a cavity wall insulation firm to do it as a side job, but there are no common resources for DIYing.

Comment: @isherwood the loft *is* the roof.  The ceiling has fibreglass insulation on top of it. The loft is the space above the insulation.  The upper surface of that space is the roof timbers and tiles.  The ventilation is for the roof timbers, but you do it by ventilating the loft space, either by air bricks, vented tiles or soffit vents.  In the OP's case it's possible filling this gap will block soffit vents, in which case tile vents may be needed.

Comment: Fair enough, @user1908704. As noted, it's a UK v US thing. Yet another way we're two countries separated by a common language.

Answer (score 2):

Insulation companies aren't interested in putzy work like this. They want speed and volume to find a profit. You probably need an experienced handyperson who's willing to take the time to resolve all the little issues that come up with a job like this, such as access and preserving **airflow under the roof deck**. You might seek a cost-plus our hourly arrangement you're comfortable with, as any bids are likely to be inflated to cover unknowns.

There's no quick, generic solution to that. Ask around, read reviews, meet with and interview a candidate. It might cost you a lunch.

Alternatively, tackle it yourself. It's not rocket science, though you need to understand how your roof is ventilated and be sure to preserve that. You need to have the insulation in direct contact with the ceiling or have any resulting cavity sealed from outside airflow.